# Chrome blue input outline won't go away no matter what

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have been trying to figure this out for hours... Chrome puts a blue outline on focused input elements and after trying the usual CSS styles to force it back to having no outline, Chrome doesn't want to listen.

I've tried:

```
input {
    outline:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

and

```
input:focus {
    outline:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

with no luck at all.. looks like chrome is really trying to make this difficult.

Comment: Reset the outline on :focus should do it, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Can you provide a sample where this issue occurs?

Comment: This occurs automatically on any new Chrome browser.  The outline:none on input focus does not fix this anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Works here :) Using: Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m

Can you provide a screenshot? Are you on Windows of Mac?

Answer (score 1):

After no luck with "outline: 0" - the following fixed disabling highlighted input:

```
    box-shadow: none;
```